# Why would a constructor fail in an unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++

I'm implementing the Discrete Fourier Transform for a school assignment, and I've created a `DFT` class which constructs the transformation matrix. For some reason, when I instantiate a `DFT` object in `main()` everything works fine, but the matrix isn't constructed properly if I use the unnamed namespace.

Works:

```
int main()
{
    DFT matrix(size);
    ...
    matrix.Transform(data);
    ...
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
namespace
{
    DFT matrix(size);
}

int main()
{
    ...
    matrix.Transform(data);
    ...
}
```

Compiler bug, or am I misremembering how the unnamed namespace works?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What is `size`?  Please provide a complete, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem (and is as small as possible), and list the exact errors that the compiler emits.

Comment: See [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) for details on how to follow James' suggestion.

Comment: Apologies. First time poster, and I was in a hurry this morning. I'll update the question with a better example shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:

```
namespace
{
    DFT matrix(size);
}
```

Where does it get `size` from? Remember this would be constructed *before* running `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you can't actually call a constructor from an unnamed namespace like that so...

```
namespace {
    DFT matrix(size);
}
```

Is actually declaring a function. On the other hand,

```
namespace {
    DFT matrix;
}
```

Will work but will use the zero initializer.